Typescript (megajs) bundle webpack работает с ошибкой
Есть такой middleware для express, после сборки в webpack, сервер запускается, но при обращении к странице, получаем ошибку. При чем, если я запускаю «npm run dev» все прекрасно работает. Есть у кого-то догадки как это устранить?
Код Middleware:
import { Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import * as megajs from 'megajs';
import { FilesCache, Folders, IRequest } from '../types';

var mega: megajs.Storage | null;
var folders: Folders = {};

export var files: FilesCache = {};

export async function storage(req: IRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {

    if (mega == null) {
        mega = new megajs.Storage({
            email: 'тратата',
            password: 'тратата',
            userAgent: 'SwiftImageManager/0.1',
            autoload: true
        });

        await mega.ready;
    }

    let folder: string | null = req.params?.folder;

    try {

        if (typeof folder == 'string' && !(folder in folders)) {

            mega.root.children?.forEach((mf: megajs.MutableFile): void => {
                if (mf.name == folder) folders[folder as string] = mf;
            });

            if (!(folder in folders)) {
                throw new Error();
            } else {
                req.mega = mega;
                req.folder = folders[folder];
                next();
            }

        } else if (typeof folder != 'string')
            throw new Error();

        req.mega = mega;
        req.folder = folders[folder];
        next();

    } catch {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }
}

Параметры webpack:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    target: 'node', // Укажите цель сборки
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'swift.image.cluster.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
};

Package json:
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx ts-node src/index.ts",
    "start": "node build/swift.image.cluster.js",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "megajs": "^1.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "zod": "^3.22.4",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/express-fileupload": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  }
}

Ошибка:
TypeError: (0 , Q.default) is not a function
    at pe.defaultFetch (D:\Backup\Develop\Node.js\MegaImageServer\build\swift.image.cluster.js:2:177017)
    at pe.request (D:\Backup\Develop\Node.js\MegaImageServer\build\swift.image.cluster.js:2:177289)
    at Se.login (D:\Backup\Develop\Node.js\MegaImageServer\build\swift.image.cluster.js:2:197037)
    at new Se (D:\Backup\Develop\Node.js\MegaImageServer\build\swift.image.cluster.js:2:194848)
    at D:\Backup\Develop\Node.js\MegaImageServer\build\swift.image.cluster.js:2:4289
    at D:\Backup\Develop\Node.js\MegaImageServer\build\swift.image.cluster.js:2:3911
    at Object.next (D:\Backup\Develop\Node.js\MegaImageServer\build\swift.image.cluster.js:2:4016)
    at D:\Backup\Develop\Node.js\MegaImageServer\build\swift.image.cluster.js:2:2907
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at r (D:\Backup\Develop\Node.js\MegaImageServer\build\swift.image.cluster.js:2:2652)

Node.js v20.10.0

UPD как выяснилось (0, Q.default) это:
Object [Module] {
  AbortError: [Getter],
  FetchError: [Getter],
  Headers: [Getter],
  Request: [Getter],
  Response: [Getter],
  default: [Getter]
}

UPDv2: В файле /node_modules/megajs/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs
export default fetch;
export { Headers, Request, Response, FetchError, AbortError };

Скорее всего Q.default это попытка вызвать fetch, но почему-то он равен следующему экспорту {Headers, ...} то есть Q выглядит так:
Object [Module] {
  AbortError: [Getter],
  FetchError: [Getter],
  Headers: [Getter],
  Request: [Getter],
  Response: [Getter],
  default: Object [Module] {
     AbortError: [Getter],
     FetchError: [Getter],
     Headers: [Getter],
     Request: [Getter],
     Response: [Getter],
     default: [Getter]
   }
}


попробуйте написать import { Storage, MutableFile } from 'megajs';

Так тоже не работает, я так изначально писал, потом в процессе поиска решения изменил на «import * as megajs from 'megajs';»

возможно проблема не связана с megajs. добавьте source-maps, чтобы увидеть читаемый трейс

Я все же думаю что в нем, потому что при исключении middleware из route запроса, все работает без ошибок... Не знаю что такое source-maps, вот ссылка на готовый файл https://swift.net.ua/_static/js/swift.image.cluster.js

Насколько я выяснил проблема возникает при вызове «new megajs.Storage»

Короче ты был прав, тот костыль что я написал, работает через раз, некоторые картинки грузит, на некоторых крашится.... Пришлось отказаться от сборки и разместить все на сервере, а запускать с команды npm run start

дай ссылку, если репа открытая

Есть на версию на js, а не на typescript https://replit.com/@DienisFazil/royalgatewayimages

Но я ее немного до ума довел, потому что это код 1 года давности, за это время опыта прибавилось поэтому по лучше переписал, + на Typescript, чтобы какие никакие гарантии были

В принципе могу и на typescript выложить, на том же реплите

Залил на typescript, https://replit.com/@DienisFazil/SwiftImageCluster

MEGA_USER это твой зарегестрированный email на mega.io, ну пароль это твой пароль, APP_TOKEN это на твое усмотрение
